# Empty strings when splitting here-string

Tags: string, powershell, powershell-3.0

A spin-off question from another SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25272775/new-aduser-the-object-name-has-bad-syntax).

When splitting a here-string on carridge return + line feed [backtick]r[backtick]n I would expect the following results

```
$theString = @"
word
word
word
word
word
"@

$theString.Split("`r`n") | Measure-Object

Count    : 5
Average  : 
Sum      : 
Maximum  : 
Minimum  : 
Property :
```

Instead what I get is the following output

```
Count    : 9
Average  : 
Sum      : 
Maximum  : 
Minimum  : 
Property :
```

The extra 4 object are empty strings. Running `%{ $_.GetType().FullName}` shows all items of type `System.String`. In the aforementioned SO Question the answers account for the empty strings. I am trying to understand why they are created from the split when I wouldnt expect them to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.Split()` splits on *any* of the characters specified in the match pattern, and because `r`n is two characters, you're getting:

```
word`r    
`n    
word`r    
`n
```

Instead of specifying characters directly in your code, use the .NET [`System.Environment` enumeration's `NewLine` member](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx). Then use [`System.StringSplitOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) to remove any empty entries.

```
$theString.Split([System.Environment]::NewLine, [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) |
    measure-object
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually recommend @alroc 's solution. An alternative way is to use the `-split` operator.

```
PS P:\> $theString = @"
word
word
word
word
word
"@

$theString -split "`r`n" | Measure-Object
$theString -split [environment]::NewLine | Measure-Object


Count    : 5
Average  : 
Sum      : 
Maximum  : 
Minimum  : 
Property : 

Count    : 5
Average  : 
Sum      : 
Maximum  : 
Minimum  : 
Property :
```